# Kubernetes - multiple configuration in one Ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have different applications running in the same Kubernetes Cluster.

I would like multiple domains to access my Kubernetes Cluster and be redirected depending the domain.
For each domain I would like different annotations/configuration.

Without the annotations I have an ingress deployment such as:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontdoor
  namespace: myapps
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - foo.bar.dev
        - bar.foo.dev
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: foo.bar.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: foobar
              servicePort: 9000
            path: /(.*)
    - host: bar.foo.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: varfoo
              servicePort: 80
            path: /(.*)
```

But They need to have multiple configuration, for example, one need to have the following annotation

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "PHPSESSID"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"
```

And another would have this one

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "FCGI"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi-index: "index.php"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi-params-configmap: "example-cm"
```

**Those configurations are not compatible**, and I can't find a way to specify a configuration by host.

I also understand that it's impossible to have 2 Ingress serving External HTTP request.

So what am I not understanding / doing wrong ?

Comment: you can have multiple `Ingress`-resources, but only one Ingress-controller is used.

Comment: In that case How can I do if I want two rules with different configurations ?

Comment: What do you mean by "rules"? Please be more clear about what you want to do.

Comment: I would like multiple domains to access my Kubernetes Cluster.
For each domain I would like different annotations/configuration.

Comment: I edited my post to be more clear on what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I also understand that it's impossible to have 2 Ingress serving External HTTP request

I am not sure where you've found this but you totally can do this.

You should be able to create two separate ingress objects like following:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontdoor-bar
  namespace: myapps
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "PHPSESSID"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"

spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - bar.foo.dev
      secretName: tls-secret-bar
  rules:
    - host: bar.foo.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: barfoo
              servicePort: 80
            path: /(.*)

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontdoor-foo
  namespace: myapps
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "FCGI"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi-index: "index.php"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi-params-configmap: "example-cm"

spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - foo.bar.dev
      secretName: tls-secret-foo
  rules:
    - host: foo.bar.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: foobar
              servicePort: 9000
            path: /(.*)
```

This is a completely valid ingress configuration, and most probably the only valid one that will solve your problem.

Each ingress object configures one domain.

Comment: Thank you, I clearly need to work harder on my understanding of that Ingress part of Kubernetes.