# Multiple domains with the same path

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Assume I have 2 domains - `foo.bar.one.com` and `foo.bar.two.com`, and a common route for them - `/static/favicon.ico`

I need to get different data when I request `foo.bar.one.com/static/favicon.ico` or `foo.bar.two.com/static/favicon.ico`

I use ingresses in Kubernetes cluster to route in Nginx server with static data.

May be I can use ReGex for routing to other path in Nginx?

Comment: ingress has a host configuration for it, if they specify the host, then they can direct traffic to a different service: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#hostname-wildcards
assuming there's a different service that would serve different data based on the hostname, then they just need to specify the hostname configuration in ingress.
Please find [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64575791/19230181) and [Doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#examples) for reference .

Comment: @HemanthKumar as I aware, I can use rewrite or redirect directives in location block in nginx configuration

Comment: What are you actually looking for then? If your  issue is solved , can you please provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.